# display an image only when at least one of a specific group of radio buttons is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some radio buttons. Let's name them
A1 B1 A2 B2 C2 A3 B3 A4 C4

I want an image to be only displayed when at least one of the B radio buttons is selected.

test cases:
B1 B2 clicked - display image
A1 A2 B3 clicked - display image
A1 A3 clicked - don't display image

What I have tried?
I am trying to keep a count of radio buttons clicked belonging to radio button group B and displaying image when that count is greater than 1.
I am new to jquery and this solution looks dirty to me.

Is there any other good solution?

Update:
I forgot to mention there can be unknown number of B radio buttons on a page.

The answer provided by Angel Politis for unknown number of B won't work as .attr() only gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular check will suffice. Try something along these lines:

**JavaScript:**

```
var
    B1 = document.getElementById("B1"),
    B2 = document.getElementById("B2"),
    img = document.getElementById("image-id"),
    rad = document.getElementByClassName("radiobuttons-class"); // Class of all the buttons

for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onchange = function() {
        if (B1.checked || B2.checked) {
            img.style.display = "inline-block"; // Or whatever you want it to be
        }
        else {
            img.style.display = "none";
        };
    };
};
```

The **`if/else`** check can also be written shorter as:

```
img.style.display = (B1.checked || B2.checked) ? "inline-block" : "none";
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".radiobuttons-class").on("change", function() {
    if($("#B1").attr(checked) || $("#B2").attr(checked)) {
        $("#image-id").css("display", "inline-block");
    }
    else {
        $("#image-id").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

---

### **Edit:**

For an unknown number of **`B`** elements you can use the following code provided that you have set a class name that is the same for all **`B`** elements:

**JavaScript:**

```
var
    img = document.getElementById("image-id"),
    arrayOfElements = document.getElementsByClassName("B"),
    rad = document.getElementByClassName("radiobuttons-class");

for (var a = 0; a < rad.length; a++) {
    rad[a].onchange = function() {
        for (var b = 0; b < arrayOfElements.length; b++) {
            if (arrayOfElements[b].checked) {
                img.style.display = "inline-block";
                break;
            }
            else {
                img.style.display = "none";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".radiobuttons-class").on("change", function() {
    $(".B").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr(checked)) {
            $("#image-id").css("display", "inline-block");
            return false; /* Break out of the loop */
        }
        else {
            $("#image-id").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In an `onchange` listener? otherwise the display of the image will be set once and never change.

Comment: Of course. I should have clarified it since the OP is a beginner. Thanks @StephenP

Comment: What if we don't want to hardcode B? What if there can be unknown number of B on a page?

Comment: But attr() only gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements. So I don't think your jquery code would work